# Fidel API giving 401 when calling from java code

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection, request-headers

I am trying to call Fidel's APIs from my java code, this API needs just a key for authentication that we need to pass in headers.
when I hit the API from postman it works. but from my java code, it throws 401.

here is postman call:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCnNq.png)

and this is my java code:

```
URL url = new URL(environment.getBaseUrl() + "offers");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Fidel-Key", "my-secret-key-here");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = ow.writeValueAsString(fidelCreateOfferRequest);

    try (OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }

    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Http Status: " + status);

    BufferedReader in;
    if (status == 200) {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("cannot create offer. failed with status: " + status);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what Fidel is, but perhaps it has produced some logs explaining the status? Perhaps the response contains an explanation?

Comment: No there is no specific detail in the response and we don't have access to the logs. the same request with same key is successful in postman, but in java it fails. so I was wondering if there is any issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was not sending one of the fields in request body, didn't notice that earlier.